# Limit page creations by user role functions.php

Tags: php, function, user-roles, restrictions

Is it possible to create a function via functions.php that restricts users from creating pages based on their user role? So for example, users with the user role "limited" can only create 5 pages.

When they reach this amount, the "Create new page" button must be gone or they have te receive a message that they reached there limit and have to contact there admin.

I know there is a plugin called Bainternet Posts Creation Limits but this is causing some problems.

Is something possible with a function?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I tried the code below but aint working and to be honest my coding skills are to poor to make something of it.

Anybody else any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

**Step 1:** Upon user creation: give your user the capability 'publish_pages'

**Step 2:** Save in the user_meta how many pages the user has created.

**Step 3:** If the user has 5 or more pages remove the capability from this user.

STEP 1 & 2 (untested):

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'user_registered', 10, 1 );

function user_registered( $user_id ) {

    // ADD CAPABILITY
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    if ( ! empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) && in_array( 'YOURROLEHERE', $user->roles ) ) {
        $user->add_cap( 'publish_pages');
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'numberofpages', 0);
    }     

}
```

STEP 3 (untested):

```
add_action('publish_page', 'user_published_page');

function user_published_page(){
    // GET CURRENT USER
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );

    // CHECK ROLE
    if ( ! empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) && in_array( 'YOURROLEHERE', $user->roles ) ) {
       // GET NUMBER OF PAGES CREATED
       $numberofpages = intval(get_user_meta($user_id, 'numberofpages', true));

        if($numberofpages >= 5){
            $user->remove_cap( 'publish_pages');
        } else {
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'numberofpages', $numberofpages + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Ruben, Thank you for the suggested solution. I just tested it. Created a new user and set allowed number of pages to 1 but user is stil able to create a second page...

Comment: Is the user_meta being created? Can you debug this code?

Comment: user_meta is created but it is stuck at 1 I think... I added 3 pages now and it stil is 1